# How do I know when a javascript method ends

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I'm just trying to learn Ext Js.
I have something like:

```
    handler: function (checkBox, checked) {
                setLoading(true);

                grid1.filterExpired(checked);
                grid2.filterExpired(checked);
                grid3.filterExpired(checked);
                if (certain condition) {
                    me.recalculateSalesPayoutValues();
                    grid4.filterExpired(checked);
                }

                setLoading(false);
            }

    filterExpired: function (filter) {
            var me = this;
            if (filter) {
                me.store.filterBy(condition, me);
            } else {
                me.store.clearFilter();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the loading mask will be hidden before the inner methods end their calculation. I would like to hide the loading mask only when all the inner methods are finished.
How can I do that? I'm using Ext Js 4.2.0

Comment: by "inner method" I'm assuming you mean `anothermethod1` and `anothermethod2`.  Did you write these methods?  From the behaviour you're describing they are asynchronous, since `loadingMask.hide()` executes before they finish.  Check if they provide a callback argument for when they're complete or if they return promises.  Ultimately you'll need to use promises and something like jQuery's `$.when` similar to `$.when(p1, p2).then(loadingMask.hide)` to make this behave as expected.

Comment: Presumably, these inner methods are asynchronous and that's why you have this issue.  If that's the case, then they will likely either have a completion callback (that will tell you when they're done) or they will return a promise object.  You can use those to know when then are done and then hide the loadingMask only when both are done.  The specifics of how to do that depend upon the specifics of how the inner methods will notify you when they are done.  You will have to research that and add more info to your question for anyone to be more specific than that.

Comment: I edited the code so right now it's pretty close to my original code. I have no idea if the filterExpired method is asynchronous or not. As I said I'm not to familiar with javascript code. Could you please give me more hints? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you show the load mask, you (probably) jump into some "busy process" that never lets the UI update. Because JS never relinquishes control until the methods complete and then the mask hides, you never visually see the changes. The simple solution is to run the task on a short timeout:

```
mask.show();
// Give the UI a chance to update
setTimeout(function() {
    method1();
    method2();
    mask.hide();
}, 1);
```

Comment: I don't understand yet why, I'll study a little bit the setTimeout method, but you're answer helped me resolve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: `setTimeout` means the code runs on the next available space, after relinquishing control. This gives the UI a chance to update before your code jumps back in to do work.

Comment: Any idea why the loading mask image isn't spinning? It just freezes, but anyway the problem is solved, so thanks again for your explanations.

Comment: For the same reason. Once the images shows up, the control is with your code which keeps the UI from updating.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be the chaining inner method calls... So anothermethod1 will call anothermethod2....and at the end anothermethodN().

So moving "loadingMask.hide()" to the last inner method will make sure that mask/unmask will happen only when all methods executed.